# how can i open and close the same visual c# form several times?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am tyring to make a visual c# form that opens and closes 3 times to show 3 random pictures. The forms shows a different random picture each time, but it doesn't stop at the 3 times. This is what i have done so far:

```
private void NextBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LevelOnePartOne af = new LevelOnePartOne();
   int i ;
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
        af.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        af.MinimumSize = new Size(600, 300);
        this.Close();
        af.Show();
        break;
    }        
}
```

Please can someone help me. I can't find the mistake even though i have been trying for 2 days now.

Comment: Open the form only once, and change the picture inside. Not open-close-open-close-open-close

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Oh, the issue @x... shows occurs due to the i variable being reset (kind of) on close (you get a different i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `LevelOnePartOne af = new LevelOnePartOne();` inside the `for` loop so you create a new form every time you loop, instead of calling `Show` multiple times on the same form.